# Are WebSocket messages cached on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket

Strange but I cannot find any information on that: if I write a [large] message to the WebSocket stream on iOS and the execution gets back to my code, is the message already sent or somehow buffered?

I'm using Starscream library but it just uses CFStream-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it use

```
func CFWriteStreamWrite(_ stream: CFWriteStream!, 
    _ buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>!, 
    _ bufferLength: CFIndex) -> CFIndex
```

the write call return "The number of bytes successfully written, 0 if the stream has been filled to capacity (for fixed-length streams), or -1 if either the stream is not open or an error occurs."

So yes, they are buffered. But I think that is the only option, a write function need to have the buffer because every socket have a max buffer zsize

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code for the Starscream library](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/master/Sources/WebSocket.swift) mentioned, the library appends the send operation to a NSOperation queue:

```
private func dequeueWrite(..) {
  ...
  writeQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

and then immediately returns.
So when the one of the send methods returns, for example:

`open func write(data: Data, completion: (() -> ())? = nil)`

The message will not yet have been sent.
But as you can see you can pass a completion block to this method, that will be called when the whole message has been written to the underlying output stream. Note that this doesn't tell you anything about whether the message has actually been sent on the network, or if the sender has received it successfully. 
To know if the sender has received and processed the message successfully, you need to wait for a response message - that is something you need to define in your application protocol.

Before using the Starscream library in production, you might want to report/fix some issues in it. While reviewing the send mechanism I noticed that if the OutputStream buffer is full on [WebSocket.swift line 1254](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/master/Sources/WebSocket.swift#L1254) the library tries sending the rest of the buffer in a busy loop rather than waiting for a `hasSpaceAvailable` event.  This may waste a lot of CPU cycle if you send a large message.
Also, it looks like the case when `stream.write` returns 0, indicating that the output buffer is full, is incorrectly handled as an error.